# Multiply every item in a column in pandas with another df generating new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm trying to multiply every column in a dataframe like so:

|  | col1 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | ... |
| 1 | 1 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... |

With another dataframe that like this:

|  | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 10 | 12 |
| b | 11 | 13 |

But also generate new columns like this:

|  | col1_x_a | col1_x_b | col1_y_a | col1_y_b | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 *(1x10)* | 11 *(1x11)* | 12 *(1x12)* | 13 *(1x13)* | ... |
| 1 | 10 *(1x10)* | 11 *(1x11)* | 12 *(1x12)* | 13 *(1x13)* | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I was wondering if there is a fast and efficient way to do this?
I tried a bunch of things like using `apply()`, `concat()` or even resorting to an elementwise multiplication using numpy but to no avail. Does someone who knows better have some suggestions to tackle this problem? I'd really appreciate it if you could help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an idea to take advantage of matrix multiplication for speed. The order of the columns is a bit different than what you wanted, but hopefully this is still useful

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import scipy as scp

# Create a large matrix, A, to multiply df1 against
# Df1*A = Y
#
# Y needs to have (df1.rows) rows by (df1.cols*df2.cols*df2.rows) columns
#
# So A will have the shape of (df1.cols) rows by (df1.cols*df2.cols*df2.rows) columns
#
# A is just diagonal matrices hstacked together, where the diagonal element is the value in Df2
#
# Using scp.sparse matrices for A to avoid too much memory use

np.random.seed(1)


df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    'col2':[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19],
    'col3':[21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29],
})


data = {}
n_df2_rows = 3 #control how many rows for Df2
n_df2_cols = 3 #control how many cols for Df2
for i in range(n_df2_rows):
    data['C'+str(i)] = np.random.randint(1,10,n_df2_cols)


df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    data,
    index=['R{}'.format(i) for i in range(n_df2_cols)],
)

r1,c1 = df1.shape
r2,c2 = df2.shape

A = scp.sparse.hstack([scp.sparse.eye(c1,dtype=np.int8)*v for v in df2.values.flatten('F')])

Y = pd.DataFrame(df1.values @ A) #@ is sparse matrix multiplication
Y.columns = ['{}_{}_{}'.format(c,v,i) for i,v,c in itertools.product(df2.columns,df2.index,df1.columns)]
Y
```

Df2 using np.random.seed(1)

[image: df2]

Output

[image: output]

Even when Df2 is 100 by 100 (and the output has 30,000 columns) this code runs in less than a minute for me

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you!